# Calculating the constants for Runge-Kutta order 4 in other form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, runge-kutta-methods

I know why Runge-Kutta order 4 can be written in the below form I guess. But I don't know how I should go about to calculate the constants required.
Runge-Kutta order 4 can also be written in the below form:
$$w_0 = \alpha_{0}$$
$$
w_{i+1} = w_i
\begin{aligned}[t]&+\frac{h}{6}
f(t_i, w_i)
\\&+\frac{h}{3}f(t_i+\alpha_1h,w_i+\delta_1f(t_i,w_i))
\\&+\frac{h}{3}f(t_i+\alpha_2h,w_i+\delta_2hf(t_i+\gamma_2h,w_i+\gamma_3hf(t_i,w_i)))
\\&+\frac{h}{6}f(t_i+\alpha_3h,w_i+\delta_3hf(t_i+\gamma_4h,w_i+\gamma_5hf(t_i+\gamma_6h,w_i+\gamma_7hf(t_i,w_i))))
\end{aligned}$$
How should I find out the constants $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$, $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$, $\delta_3$, $\gamma_2$, $\gamma_3$, $\gamma_4$, $\gamma_5$, $\gamma_6$, $\gamma_7$ ?
I tried to somehow write the Taylor expansion for the function and compare the coefficients but my solution led to some unsolvable equations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Derivation_of_the_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_fourth-order_method

Comment: @caverac But the one in the wikipedia is not in the form I have posed the question.

Comment: This does not make sense. Where does this problem come from? RK4 requires 4 evaluations of $f$ per step. The form you wrote requires up to $7$ evaluations of $f$, why make this over-general formula?

Comment: Essentially, you are asking about the order equations for the Butcher tableau
\begin{array}{l|lllllll}
0&\\
α_1&δ_1 \\
γ_2&γ_3 \\
α_2&0&0&δ_1 \\
γ_6&γ_7 \\
γ_4&0&0&0&0&γ_5 \\
α_2&0&0&0&0&0&δ_1 \\ \hline
&\frac16&\frac13&0&\frac13&0&0&\frac16
\end{array}

Comment: @LutzL This a Numerical Analysis, Burden book problem in section 5.4 problem 30 and it does make sense but I don't know how to proceed to find those coefficients. If you have any other solution explain further.

Comment: @FreeMind: I think you misunderstood the exercise. The task is not to *derive* these constants from some order conditions, but rather to *start with the classical fourth-order Runge-Kutta method* for the initial-value problem $w' = f(t,w)$, $w(t_0)=\alpha_0$, and to rewrite it in the form above, which gives you the values of the constants.

Comment: Actually, it is problem 32 in the 9th edition going by the [solution site chegg.com](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/runge-kutta-method-order-four-written-form-chapter-5.4-problem-32e-solution-9780538735636-exc). The type of the previous tasks and that it is an introductory chapter confirm the task interpretation of @Christoph.